# Outline a raster cell of interest by cell number

Tags: r, plot, selection, cell, raster

I would like to outline a raster cell given the cell number in a plot. I have made a simplified example, that I was able to make in power point, but may have a resolution that will be more difficult to do this for (720 x 360 vs 3 x 5).
To generate the sample data:

```
library(raster)
x = raster(matrix(seq(1,15), nrow = 3))
plot(x)
```

And I would like a modification to the plot command (preferably) so that if I were to select the 5th cell, the result looks something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a general approach, where we plot an `extent` based on the row and column of the cell of interest.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(matrix(1:15, nrow=3))
plot(r)
rc <- rowColFromCell(r, 5)
plot(extent(r, rc[1], rc[1], rc[2],  rc[2]), add=TRUE, col='red', lwd=3)
```

[image: fig1]

The second through fourth arguments to `extent` determine the span of rows (args 2 and 3) and columns (args 4 and 5) that will be used to calculate the extent.

If we wanted to outline cells 3, 4, 8, and 9, we could do:

```
plot(r)
rc <- rowColFromCell(r, c(3, 4, 8, 9))
plot(extent(r, min(rc[, 1]), max(rc[, 1]), 
            min(rc[, 2]),  max(rc[, 2])), add=TRUE, col='red', lwd=3)
```

[image: fig2]

This works fine for rectangular extents around contiguous sets of cells. If you want to outline an arbitrary selection of cells, you could consider `rasterToPolygons`. E.g. for cells 2, 8, 9, 11, and 14:

```
plot(r)
r2 <- r
r2[setdiff(seq_len(ncell(r2)), c(2, 8, 9, 11, 14))] <- NA
r2[!is.na(r2)] <- 1
plot(rasterToPolygons(r2, dissolve=TRUE), add=TRUE, border='red', lwd=2)
```

Here, we create a copy of the raster, set all *other* cells to `NA`, and then the focal cells to a common value (`1`, in this case). `rasterToPolygons` then converts the non-NA cells to polygons, dissolving touching polys if desired.

[image: fig3]

Answer (score 2):

This code should do what you want.

```
plot(raster(matrix(seq(1,15), nrow = 3)))

gridx = 5
gridy = 3
dx = 1/gridx #resolution of the grid 
dy = 1/gridy

# if you want to specify the cell number (cell 1 is bottom left):

cell = 15
ny = floor(cell/gridx - dx)+1
nx = cell-gridx*(ny-1)

# if you want to give cell positions, just edit nx, ny

x1 = c(nx-1,nx-1,nx-1,nx)*dx
y1 = c(ny-1,ny,ny-1,ny-1)*dy
x2 = c(nx,nx,nx-1,nx)*dx
y2 = c(ny-1,ny,ny,ny)*dy

segments(x1,y1,x2,y2,col=2,lwd=2)
```

Comment: Thanks - doesn't quite do it by cell number - but easy enough to figure out the row and col (nx and ny) values given the cell number.